# Pass self automatically in lambda function?

Tags: python, class, parsing, lambda, self

Is there a way to automatically pass self to a lambda function in a class? I know I can pass self in the `__init__` function but then I'm redefining `token_functions` for every instance of `Parser`. `token_functions` never changes so this seems quite inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

```
class Parser:
    token_functions = {r'\n': lambda: Parser.new_line(self)}

    def __init__(self):
        self.line_number = 0
        Parser.token_functions[r'\n']()
    
    def new_line(self):
        self.line_number += 1
        print(self.line_number)
    
Parser()
```

Comment: It would help if you showed more context of how you intend to use the `Parser` class and redefine `token_functions` for each instance.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych It will give you an error`NameError`.

Comment: Oh, right, `Parser` is not defined yet.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Yeah but you can access it in any function`__init__, new_line, Or, lambda`.

Comment: Probably user gets an error because the self is not defined Yet.

Comment: *redefining* and *never changes*: the reason is that your class design looks doubtful, it's not about how to pass `self` somewere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The function created by the lambda expression is not a class attribute, so the descriptor protocol is not triggered.

You *could* call its `__get__` method directly, e.g. `Parser.token_functions[r'\n'].__get__(self, type(self))()`, but you probably don't want to be dealing with the low-level machinery directly.

Just define the function to accept an object with a `new_line` method as an explicit argument, and pass `self` when the time comes.

```
class Parser:
    token_functions = {r'\n': lambda obj: obj.new_line()}

    def __init__(self):
        self.line_number = 0
        Parser.token_functions[r'\n'](self)
    
    def new_line(self):
        self.line_number += 1
        print(self.line_number)
```

The `operator` module provides a `methodcaller` function to replace this use of a lambda expression.

```
token_functions = {'\n': operator.methodcaller('new_line')}
```

Comment: This works. Just out of curiosity. Is this the same as token_functions = {r'\n': lambda obj: Parser.new_line(obj)}? Both seem to work.

Comment: More or less. The difference come up if you decide to subclass `Parser`, in which case `self.new_line()` would a subclass's override of `new_line` be used.